# Implementing product upload dynamically using Django 1.6

Tags: python, ajax, django

So I am using my admin interface to add product information for different items that will be on my site. I am looking to add the product information from my models to a template view, but I would like for every time I add a new product using my admin interface, for the template to generate a new Li tag with the current product information and picture used of the entered data within the admin interface.

I have not yet implemented any template logic in my views.py yet I am stumped on how to really wrap my head around making this whole process happen. So can anyone help guide me on how to implement this solution?

**Thank You!**

Here is my code below:

**Models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

import datetime

class Designer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    label_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    specialites = models.CharField(max_length=254,  null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/designers/main',max_length=100, null=True) #For the argument upload_to, will add to the static folder and generated image will be stored in suing that path specified

    #For Admin Purposes, to track and see which if still active by for administrative users only
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    #Metadata
    class Meta:
       verbose_name = _("Designer Information")
       verbose_name_plural = _("Designers")

    #Helps return something meaningful, to show within the admin interface for easy interaction
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0} {1}".format(self.name, self.label_name)

class Boutique(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)    
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    boutique_website = models.URLField(max_length=200,  null=True, blank=True)

    #For Admin Purposes, to track a product to see which is active by administrative users
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    #Foreign Keys & other relationships
    designer = models.ForeignKey(Designer)

    #Metadata
    class Meta:
      verbose_name = _("Boutique Information")
      verbose_name_plural = _("Boutiques")

    #Helps return something meaningful, to show within the admin interface for easy interaction
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0}, {1}, {2}".format(self.name, self.city, self.state)

class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, help_text='Unique value for product page URL, created from name.')

    #For Admin Purposes, to track and see which if still active by for administrative users only
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    #For Admin Purposes, to track when we add each product and each product was updated by administrative users
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    #Metadata
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Product Category")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Product Categories")

    #Helps return something meaningful, to show within the admin interface for easy interaction
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.name)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)    
    color_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    size_types = models.CharField(max_length=7, null=True, blank=True)
    product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)
    old_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2, blank=True,default=0.00) #To show original price if, new price has been added
    product_tags = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True, help_text='Comma-delimited set of SEO keywords for product tag area')
    novelty = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    product_website = models.URLField(max_length=200,  null=True, blank=True) #To show other sites to Users, where they can purchase the particular product
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/products/main',max_length=100, null=True) #For the argument upload_to, will add to the static folder and generated image will be stored in suing that path specified
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, help_text='Unique value for product page URL, created from name.')

  #This shows when each item was uploaded & by who, to the User 
    uploaded_by = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  #For Admin Purposes, to track and see which if still active by for administrative users only
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    #Foreign Keys & other relationships
    designer = models.ForeignKey(Designer)
    boutique = models.ForeignKey(Boutique)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory)

    #Metadata
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Product")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Products")

    #Helps return something meaningful, to show within the admin interface for easy interaction
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.name)
```

**Admin.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib import admin
from products.models import Designer, Product, ProductCategory, Boutique


class DesignerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ["name", "label_name", "description", "specialites", "image", "is_active"]
    search_fields = ["name", "label_name"]
    list_per_page = 50

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ["name", "description", "color_name", "size_types", "product_price", "old_price", "product_tags", "novelty","product_website", "image", "slug", "uploaded_by", "uploaded_at", "is_active"]
    search_fields = ["name", "product_price"]
    list_per_page = 25

class ProductCategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 

    list_display = ["name", "slug", "is_active", "created_at", "updated_at"]
    search_fields = ["name"]
    list_per_page = 25

class BoutiqueAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ["name", "address", "city", "state", "zipcode", "boutique_website", "is_active"]
    search_fields = ["name"]
    list_per_page = 10


#Register Models below
admin.site.register(Boutique, BoutiqueAdmin)
admin.site.register(Designer, DesignerAdmin)
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
admin.site.register(ProductCategory, ProductCategoryAdmin)
```

**Forms.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django import forms

from django.forms import extras, ModelForm

from products.models import Designer, Product, ProductCategory, Boutique

class DesignerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Designer

class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product

class BoutiqueForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Boutique

class ProductCategoryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductCategory
```

**Views.Py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseForbidden
from django.shortcuts import redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.utils.http import base36_to_int, int_to_base36
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateResponseMixin, View
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

from django.contrib import auth, messages
from django.contrib.sites.models import get_current_site
from django.shortcuts import render

from products.forms import ProductForm, ProductCategoryForm
from products.forms import BoutiqueForm
from products.forms import DesignerForm

from products.models import Boutique, Product, ProductCategory, Designer



class ProductView(FormView):

    template_name = "product_detail/product.html"
    form_class = ProductForm
    template_var={}


    def __init__(self, *arg):
        super(ProductView, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg



class ProductCategoryView(FormView):

    form_class = ProductCategoryForm
    template_var={}


    def __init__(self, *arg):
        super(ProductCategory, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is a simple `ListView` from Django's generic class-based views.

### First, string up your `views.py`:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class ProductListView(ListView):

    model = Product
    template_name = 'product/list_view.html' # Edit this to whatever your template is.
```

### Remember to edit your `urls.py`:

```
from .views import ProductListView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^product/$', ProductListView.as_view(), name='list'), # Edit url path and name as desired
    ...
)
```

### Then, make your template:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <ul>
    {% for product in products %}
        <li>{{ product.name }}: {{ product.description }} <img src="{{ product.image.url }}" >
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is a very basic template which you'll obviously want to customize. For each `Product` in your database, it will display the name, description, and the image. You can customize your fields as you desire.

### Other potential issues:

1) Be sure you provide the correct path to your template in your `ListView`.

2) Set up your `MEDIA_URL` and other media settings to allow your `Product` image to display.

3) Look at other customization options in `ListView` (see documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview).)